# how to add a variable input to a flutter default widget?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add an optional variable to a flutter default widget but the widget's file is so confusing. any idea how can I do that?
I want to add a variable named customText to this widget:

```
showDatePicker(
      //customText://
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));)
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass extra information then create your own widget which takes parameters and returns your wished widget.

```
class CustomDatePicker extends StatelessWidget {

  final String customString;

  CustomDatePicker({Key key, this.customString}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Do whatever you want with your custom String
    return showDatePicker(
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Create a stateful widget if the string is dynamic (changeable).

Yours Glup3